# ERR! while running node.js app

Tags: node.js

Whenever I try to run node.js application, I get error messages though application runs successfully. Just curious what does these errors really mean.

Here is the output from the console while running a simple node.js application:

```
npm ERR! node v6.11.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! app-service-hello-world@0.0.1 start: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the app-service-hello-world@0.0.1 start script 'node index.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the app-service-hello-world package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node index.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs app-service-hello-world
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls app-service-hello-world
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: You're using a service which asks for a recent enough version of node and you use a very old one.

Comment: Will updating node fix these issues?